# How do you reuse a selenium webdriver browser instance between cucumber-js tests?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am writing end to end tests using Selenium webdriver and cucumber-js. At the moment I'm attaching the driver instance to the cucumber 'world' like so:

```
function CustomWorld({attach, parameters}) {
    this.driver = new seleniumWebdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .build();
}

setWorldConstructor(CustomWorld)
```

which allows me to call methods on the driver in my step definitions. Unfortunately this also reopens a new browser session for each scenario. I would like to be able to write tests which reuse a browser session when needed, does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Best practice is to have a separate browser for each test. It keeps each run cleaner and makes it less likely that a previous run affects the next run. Also, tests should be able to run in any order and should not be dependent on each other.